# functools has no 'lru_cache' installing Django

Tags: python, django

```
$ pip install django
Collecting django
  Using cached Django-2.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-capC7C/django/setup.py", line 32, in <module>
        version = __import__('django').get_version()
      File "django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from django.utils.version import get_version
      File "django/utils/version.py", line 61, in <module>
        @functools.lru_cache()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-capC7C/django/
```

Comment: What have you researched and attempted to troubleshoot?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to install Django for Python 3 on Python 2.

Comment: I've edited the title here to be self-contained -- please try not to refer to "this" code or "this" error; such titles are effectively clickbait, since they mean someone can't know what the question is about until they click through; consequently, someone trying to figure out if they have the same problem or if they know enough to fix the issue can't figure it out from the title alone even if they otherwise could.

Answer (score 4):

[From Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#python-compatibility):

> Python compatibility
>
> Django 2.0 supports Python 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6. We highly recommend and
> only officially support the latest release of each series.
>
> The Django 1.11.x series is the last to support Python 2.7.

[`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) appeared in Python 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [supported Python version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/faq/install/#faq-python-version-support).